# Upload IOS Apps without an IPhone nor Macbook

Tags: ios, upload, publish

Is it possible to upload an app on App Store without owning an Apple gadget? I have created an Apple ID but I do not think this is enough because I am required to do two-factor authentication.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to upload an application/game without Xcode. And Xcode is only available in macOS.

- It's necessary that your Apple ID also has been enrolled for the developer account. You can visit here for that: https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/
- And that Apple ID requires two-factor authentication as well from any iOS or macOS device.
- Then after the certificates have been created for the particular application.
- These certificates will be used from Xcode to upload the application/game.
- Of course in new Xcode, certificates can also be created dynamically & automatically.

Answer (score 1):

After being an enrolled developer you still need to build app on a Mac to submit to the App Store. In case you do not or can not have a Mac you may use a cloud service (like MacInCloud, MacStadium, ... ) that enables you to use a virtual Mac to build and upload an app to the App Store. You can then use the iOS simulator to test your app but it will always be better to have at least one real device to test as some functionalities either are not available in the simulator or do not work exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like Odevio (https://odevio.com/)

For Flutter application it provides a solution for configuring Xcode, generating an .ipa file as well as publishing your app on the app store.

Of course you will still need an active Apple Developer subscription.